# Hadoop command not working

Tags: hadoop

I have a folder called HadoopExperiment which contains MapReduce java files. In my terminal, when I do hadoop -fs ls in this path (myName/workspace/HadoopExperiment/bin), it tells me that the command "hadoop" is not found.

However, when I run the same command in the path in which I have installed hadoop, the command works fine.

Can someone tell me how I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Add your hadoop/bin path in your $PATH system environment.

Comment: Where can I find the $PATH system env?

Comment: This is my path: 
echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/juan/hadoop/hadoop1.2.1/bin

Comment: if '/home/juan/hadoop/hadoop1.2.1/' is the path you have installed hadoop, then you can run hadoop in any path. It's weird.  XD

Comment: Any other suggestions ?